# JQuery AJAX PHP Session not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I am struggling to figure out why my PHP session varriables are not working with JQuery and AJAX. Below you can find some code, after the user is done the form `#enterUsername` they successfully get the result from `email.php`. This is because that code is the original receiver of the POST so it relies on that, but everything after that fails to get the session vars which rely on it.

**NOTE: It is a lot of code and I know I am asking for a lot. I recommend if you wish to help that you just skim through it super quick and then start inspecting my session vars.**

### Code:

#### Landing Page

```
<html>
<head>

<?php
  // Remove Any Previous Session
  session_start();
  session_destroy(); // I tried commenting this out
?>

// Irrelevant Lines Removed from Head
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loginContainer">
  <div id="loginBox">
    <div id="login">
      <div id="loading" class="hidden"></div>
      <form action="email.php" method="post" id="enterUsername">
        <h4>Username:</h4>
        <input type="text" class="input" style="cursor: text;" name="username" maxlength="40" autocomplete="off">
        <p><b>Example: XXXXXXXX</b></p>
        <?php
          require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/recaptcha.php';
          DisplayReCaptcha();
        ?>
        <input type="submit" class="input" value="Continue">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="status">
<?php
  // For Error Handling
  if(!empty($_SESSION["ReCaptcha_Reason"])) {
    echo '<div class="error"><span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display=\'none\';">&times;</span><h4>' . $_SESSION["ReCaptcha_Reason"] . '</h4></div>';
    $_SESSION["ReCaptcha_Reason"] = "";
  }
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### index.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get Username Form...
    var UsernameForm = $('#enterUsername');

    // Catch Username Form...
    $(UsernameForm).submit(function(event) {
        // Catch Browser Submitting Form
        event.preventDefault();

        // Hide UsernameForm...
        $("#enterUsername").hide();

        // Error Message Response Removal
        $(".success, .error, .warning, .info").remove();

        // Start Loading
        $("#loading").removeClass("hidden");

        // Serialize the form data
        var formData = $(UsernameForm).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: $(UsernameForm).attr('method'),
            url: $(UsernameForm).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })

        .done(function(response) {
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                // Done Loading
                $("#loading").addClass("hidden");

                if(response == "REFRESH") {
                  location.reload();
                } else if(response.startsWith("Error")) {
                  // Error Message Adding
                  $(".status").append("<div class=\"error\"><span class=\"closebtn\" onclick=\"this.parentElement.style.display='none';\">" +
                  "&times;</span>" + response.replace("Error", "") + "</div>");

                  // Show Form Again
                  $("#enterUsername").show();
                } else {
                  // Remove UsernameForm...
                  $("#enterUsername").hide();

                  // Set the message text.
                  $("#login").append(response);
                }
            }, 1000)
        })
    });

    $(document).arrive("#enrollNow", function() {
      // Get EnrollNowButton...
      var EnrollNowButton = $('#enrollNow');

      // Catch EnrollNowButton...
      $(EnrollNowButton).click(function(event) {
          // Hide EnrollNowButton Container...
          $("#enrollNowContainer").hide();

          // Error Message Response Removal
          $(".success, .error, .warning, .info").remove();

          // Start Loading
          $("#loading").removeClass("hidden");

          // Submit the form using AJAX.
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/core/enrollnow.php"
          })

          .done(function(response) {
              window.setTimeout(function(){
                // Done Loading
                $("#loading").addClass("hidden");

                if(response.startsWith("Error")) {
                  // Error Message Response Adding
                  $(".status").append("<div class=\"error\"><span class=\"closebtn\" onclick=\"this.parentElement.style.display='none';\">" +
                  "&times;</span>" + response.replace("Error", "") + "</div>");

                  // Show Form Again
                  $("#enrollNowContainer").show();
                } else {
                  // Remove EnrollNowButton Container...
                  $("#enrollNowContainer").remove();

                  // Increase height
                  $("#loginContainer").height("70%");

                  // Set the message text.
                  $("#login").append(response);
                }
              }, 1000)
          })
      });
    });

    $(document).arrive("#enrollPhase1", function() {
      // Get EnrollPhase1 Form...
      var EnrollPhase1Form = $('#enrollPhase1');

        // Serialize the form data
        var formData = $(EnrollPhase1Form).serialize();

        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: $(EnrollPhase1Form).attr('method'),
            url: $(EnrollPhase1Form).attr('action'),
            data: formData
        })

        .done(function(response) {
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $("#loading").addClass("hidden");

                if(response == "REFRESH") {
                  location.reload();
                } else if(response.startsWith("Error")) {
                  // Error Message Adding
                  $(".status").append("<div class=\"error\"><span class=\"closebtn\" onclick=\"this.parentElement.style.display='none';\">" +
                  "&times;</span>" + response.replace("Error", "") + "</div>");

                  // Increase height
                  $("#loginContainer").height("70%");

                  // Show Form Again
                  $("#enrollPhase1Container").show();
                } else {
                  // Remove UsernameForm...
                  $("#enrollPhase1Container").remove();

                  // Decrease height
                  $("#loginContainer").height("50%");

                  // Set the message text.
                  $("#login").append(response);
                }
            }, 1000)
        })
    });
  });
});
```

#### email.php

```
<?php    
  // Check For Username Submission
  if($_POST["username"] === "") {
    die("Error<h4>No Username Entered</h4>");
  }
  if(!isset($_POST["username"])) {
    die("Error<h4>Server is Missing Data</h4>");
  }

  // Check ReCaptcha and Add For Username Not Found
  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/recaptcha.php';
  if(isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"])) {
    $ReCaptcha = GetReCaptchaResults("6LfRakIUAAAAAGYkxaO1iswoxDt4QTcA82AyXhXL", $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]);
    $ReCaptcha = json_decode($ReCaptcha, true);

    if($ReCaptcha["success"] !== true) {
      // See Note At Top
      TriggerReCaptcha("ReCaptcha Human Test Failed");
      die("REFRESH");
    }
  }

  // Start Session and Save UsernameForm
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];

  // Get User
  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/user.php';
  $User = GetUser($_POST["username"]);

  // Does The User Exist
  if($User === "Error - User Not Found") {
    // See Note At Top
    TriggerReCaptcha("User Not Found");
    die("REFRESH");
  }

  // User Is Legit
  TerminateReCaptcha();

  // Check For Disabled Account
  if($User["UserDisabled"] === "True") {
    die('<div id="enrollNowContainer"><h4>' . $User["DisplayName"] . ',</h4><b><p>Your Account is Disabled</p></b><br><p>Your IT staff has disabled your account from being used.</p>');
  }

  // Check for Enrollment
  if(empty($User["SecurityQuestion1"]) || empty($User["SecurityAnswer1"]) ||
  empty($User["SecurityQuestion2"]) || empty($User["SecurityAnswer2"]) || empty($User["BackUpEmail"])) {
    // Not Enrolled
    die('<div id="enrollNowContainer"><h4>' . $User["DisplayName"] . ',</h4><p>Your Account is not Enrolled</p><br><br><button class="input" id="enrollNow">Enroll Now</button></div>');
  } else {
    echo '
        <button class="input" id="resetPassword">Reset Password</button><br><br>
        <button class="input" id="changeSettings">Change Setttings</button>';
  }
?>
```

#### enrollnow.php

**(First page that requires sessions...)**

```
<?php
  // Open Session
  session_start();

  // Check For Username Submission
  if($_SESSION["username"] === "") {
    die("Error<h4>No Username Entered</h4>");
  }
  if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
    die("Error<h4>Server is Missing Data</h4>");
  }

  // Get User
  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/user.php';
  $User = GetUser($_SESSION["username"]);
  if($User === "Error - User Not Found") {
    die("Error<h4>User Not Found</h4>");
  }

  // Check for Enrollment
  if(empty($User["SecurityQuestion1"]) || empty($User["SecurityAnswer1"]) ||
  empty($User["SecurityQuestion2"]) || empty($User["SecurityAnswer2"]) || empty($User["BackUpEmail"])) {
    // Not Enrolled
    StartEnrollment();
  }

  function StartEnrollment() {
    $FinalHTML = '<div id="enrollPhase1Container"><form action="/core/enrollphase1.php" method="post" id="enrollPhase1">';

    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/core/sq.php';

    // Security Question 1

    $FinalHTML .= '<select name="SecurityQuestion1" class="input">';

    foreach (GetSecurityQuestions() as $ArrayID => $Question) {
      $FinalHTML .= '<option value="' . $Question["ID"] . '">' . $Question["Question"] . '</option>';
    }

    $FinalHTML .= '</select><br><br>';

    $FinalHTML .= '<input type="text" class="input" id="SecurityAnswer1"></input><br><br>';

    // Security Question 2

    $FinalHTML .= '<select name="SecurityQuestion2" class="input">';

    foreach (GetSecurityQuestions() as $ArrayID => $Question) {
      $FinalHTML .= '<option value="' . $Question["ID"] . '">' . $Question["Question"] . '</option>';
    }

    $FinalHTML .= '</select><br><br>';

    $FinalHTML .= '<input type="text" class="input" id="SecurityAnswer2"></input><br><br>';
    $FinalHTML .= '<input type="submit" class="input" value="Continue"></input></form></div>';

    die($FinalHTML);
  }
?>
```

Comment: I did remove as much code as I though would help. If you feel it is too much I understand if you wish to overlook this.

Comment: Have you done debugging in your browser's dev tools, specifically checking if the php session cookie is being sent and received (created) during ajax calls?

Comment: Also your landing page has `session_start();` a bit low in the output chain. It should always be above anything that gets output (if you wish to utilize cookie based sessions). Also toss this on the very top of your files, which can shed some light on possible infectious issues: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Where exactly do you get which error? "No Username Entered" or "Server is Missing Data" in enrollnow.php?

Comment: @masterfloda "Server is Missing Data", and the session var is empty.

Comment: @IncredibleHat A little bit of AJAX debugging, and after testing with all your error catching options there are no errors on the page when I force set session on another page.

Comment: Well... I guess no errors being reported is a good sign. Now you just need to figure out why no session data is being pulled by php from the cookie token ;)

Comment: I don't see any obvious bugs in your code. Is there any session handling in `recaptcha.php` or `user.php`? Also, try to narrow down the problem: What happens if you create two simple files, do a `session_start()` in both, set a session variable in one and echo it in the other. If that works, something is wrong in your code. If not, the problem is with your server.

Comment: I LOVE YOU! @masterfloda OMG! I FORGOT `recaptcha.php` was a custom script! YOU ARE THE BEST!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution:

In recaptcha.php I had a function called `TerminateReCaptcha()` that destroyed the session rather than removing the recaptcha required page.